# Why isn't the determinant of a squared matrix negative?

Tags: matrices, determinant

When a square matrix is squared, then why isn't its determinant negative?

For example, in the $2 \times 2$ matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2  \\ 3 & 4 \end{pmatrix}^2 = \begin{pmatrix} 7 & 10  \\ 15 & 22 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$\begin{vmatrix}
    7 & 10  \\
    15 & 22  \\
    \end{vmatrix} = 154 - 150 = +4$$
i.e in 2*2 matrix, the determinant of the squared matrix, the product of the left diagonal always become greater than the product of the right diagonal.

I just can't figured out, why?

Thanks.

[edit]: If the determinant is not zero or it has a solution.

Comment: $\det A^2=(\det A)^2$.

Answer (score 3):

That is because the determinant of a matrix product of square matrices equals the product of their determinants.
$$\text{det}(AB)=\text{det}(A)\text{det}(B).$$
More on this can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Multiplicativity_and_matrix_groups). So the determinant of $A^2$ becomes $(\text{det}(A))^2,$ which is of course non-negative.

Answer (score -1):

Because the determinant function is multiplicative (i.e. $\operatorname{det}(AB)=\operatorname{det}(A)\operatorname{det}(B))$ and the square of any real number is nonnegative.

Comment: *is nonnegative. $0^2 = 0$.